# Scrapyd + Django in Docker: HTTPConnectionPool (host = '0.0.0.0', port = 6800) error

Tags: python, django, docker, scrapy, scrapyd

I am a young Italian boy looking for help.I'm building a web interface for my web scraper using django and scrapyd. It's my first experience with scrapy but i'm learning fast thanks to the good amount of documentation on the net. However, I find myself in quite a bit of difficulty starting my spider via scrapyd_api.ScrapydAPI. Despite starting the server at the correct port (curl and browser requests both work), django returns a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool (host = '0.0.0.0', port = 6800) error.

**First of all, here is my folder structure:**

```
    scraper
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── dbs
    │   └── default.db
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── logs
    │   └── default
    │       └── autoscout
    │           ├── 0b2585dc6f2011eba4d30242ac140002.log
    │           ├── 1fd803a66f2011eba4d30242ac140002.log
    │           └── 6fac4d646f2111eba4d30242ac140002.log
    ├── middlewares.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20210214_2019.py
    │   ├── 0003_auto_search_token.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
    │       ├── [...]
    │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── [...]
    │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── serializers.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── spiders
    │   ├── AutoScout.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── AutoScout.cpython-38.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

**and my docker compose:**

```yaml
    version: "3.9"
       
    services:
      django:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - .:/app
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
      
      scrapyd:
        build: .
        command: bash -c "cd /app/scraper && scrapyd"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - "6800:6800"
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        dns:
            - 8.8.8.8
```

**And here we go with my attempt at running the spider through scrapyd:**
*note that both versions (commented and not commented) do not work on my system, while both curl and the browser are working.*

```py
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapyd_api import ScrapydAPI

from uuid import uuid4
import requests
import os

scrapyd = ScrapydAPI('http://0.0.0.0:6800')

@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def start_crawl(request):
    search_token = uuid4()

    settings = {
        'brand' : request.POST['brand'], 
        'model' : request.POST['model'],
        'search_token' : search_token,
    }
    task = scrapyd.schedule('default', 'autoscout', settings=settings)

    # response = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:6800/schedule.json', {
    #     'project' : 'default',
    #     'spider' : 'autoscout',
    #     'brand' : 'fiat',
    #     'model' : '500',
    #     'search_token' : search_token,
    # })

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

In case you need it, this is my scrapy.cfg

```
[settings]
default = settings

[deploy]
project = .

[scrapyd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
http_port   = 6800
```

At last, the overwhelming exception produced by the code:

```
django_1   | Internal Server Error: /crawler-bot/run/
django_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
django_1   |     conn = connection.create_connection(
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
django_1   |     raise err
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
django_1   |     sock.connect(sa)
django_1   | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
django_1   | 
django_1   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1   | 
django_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
django_1   |     httplib_response = self._make_request(
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
django_1   |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
django_1   |     super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
django_1   |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
django_1   |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
django_1   |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
django_1   |     self.send(msg)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
django_1   |     self.connect()
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
django_1   |     conn = self._new_conn()
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
django_1   |     raise NewConnectionError(
django_1   | urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fef2fb73ee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
django_1   | 
django_1   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1   | 
django_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
django_1   |     resp = conn.urlopen(
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
django_1   |     retries = retries.increment(
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
django_1   |     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
django_1   | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=6800): Max retries exceeded with url: /schedule.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fef2fb73ee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
django_1   | 
django_1   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1   | 
django_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django_1   |     response = get_response(request)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
django_1   |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
django_1   |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
django_1   |     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/app/scraper/views.py", line 25, in start_crawl
django_1   |     task = scrapyd.schedule('default', 'autoscout', settings=settings)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapyd_api/wrapper.py", line 188, in schedule
django_1   |     json = self.client.post(url, data=data, timeout=self.timeout)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
django_1   |     return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapyd_api/client.py", line 37, in request
django_1   |     response = super(Client, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
django_1   |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
django_1   |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
django_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
django_1   |     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
django_1   | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=6800): Max retries exceeded with url: /schedule.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fef2fb73ee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
django_1   | [15/Feb/2021 02:16:48] "POST /crawler-bot/run/ HTTP/1.1" 500 184852
```

Thanks to anyone who will try to help me, I am very grateful to you.

*P.S.
If more code is needed, I can of course update the question.
I also apologize if my question is not the best, but it is my third time. I'm learning this too.*

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

means scrapyd can be accessed from outside network

You need to use localhost:6800 in your app to connect with scrapyd

btw, its not a good practice to allow scrapyd to be accessed publicly, anyone in the world can deploy scrapers on your server and run them, and exploits your system

Please enable `ufw` and disable access to port 6800 from outside

Comment: changing the `bind_address` to localhost, and the various links in`http: // localhost: 6800` has no effect, on the contrary: scrapyd's web interface is no longer available from the browser.